2000s(?) book series about girl with purple eyes and fantasy world
This book would be kinda old, 20 years ish. On the cover, there was girl with her eyes closed, light brown hair shoulder-length.
I don't remember the plot much, but the girl lived in modern world and one day accidentally traveled in some fantasy world, where she found out, she's actually from that world and her parents ran away from there with her.
She could travel back and forth between the worlds and that was her special power, she had purple eyes I think, that indicated that power.
She also had a boy best friend who traveled into that fantasy world with her at least once.
I'm pretty sure there was also her brother somewhere in that parallel world.
I'm not 100% sure, but that book might be written by French author? It's definitely a series, this book being the first part.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say it might be by a French author; does that mean that you read it in French?

A Princess of Roumania (2005) and sequels by Paul Park? The cover matches your description and it's about a girl, the titular princess, who was taken from an alternate universe to ours. She returns home with some friends during the course of the book.


This is a truly magical tale, full of strangeness, terrors and wonders. Many girls daydream that they are really a princess adopted by commoners. In the case of teenager Miranda Popescu, this is literally true. Because she is at the fulcrum of a deadly political battle between conjurers in an alternate world where "Roumania" is a leading European power, Miranda was hidden by her aunt in our world, where she was adopted and raised in a quiet Massachusetts college town.


The narrative is split between our world and the people in Roumania working to protect or to capture Miranda: her Aunt Aegypta Schenck versus the mad Baroness Ceaucescu in Bucharest, and the sinister alchemist, the Elector of Ratisbon, who holds her true mother prisoner in Germany. This is the story of how Miranda -- with her two best friends, Peter and Andromeda -- is brought back to her home reality. Each of them is changed in the process and all will have much to learn about their true identities and the strange world they find themselves in.


I don't see any mention of eye color in the reviews I skimmed though.

Partial match: La Quête d'Ewilan (2003) by Pierre Bottero.
Exact matches:

the release date and author's nationality; the three books are originally in French and they have not been translated, although their comic adaptation have been;
Camille, the protagonist, has purple eyes which are a key feature of the character
Camille, while living in 21st century France, is originally from the parallel world of Gwendalavir, to which she accidentally "jumps" back and forth in the first book, before learning how to control said jump
she has a male friend, Salim, who she carries with her to the other world in her second accidental jump. He stays with her throughout the story

More partial matches:

Camille does have a brother, Mathieu, who is also from the other world, but she first meets him on Earth
although being born in the other world, Camille and Mathieu's parents did not come to live on Earth with her; they placed them in the care of two adoptive families, safe from Gwendalavir's incoming war, and went back to the other world
Camille's purple eyes are not an indicator of her power (they are just unusual and beautiful)
the original cover of the first book (it has been re-edited since with other covers) shows Camille's shoulder-length hair, but her eyes are not closed:


